# Incompatible type in assignment

Tags: objective-c, iphone

Getting error: Incompatible type in assignment at fValue = ..., see the code

```
static float t = 0;        
float d = .5;        
static float fValue = 0;        
fValue = [self easeOutBounce:t andB:0 andC:30 andD:d];
```

here is the method

```
-(float) easeOutBounce:(float)t andB:(float)b andC:(float)c andD:(float)d {
    if ((t/d) < (1/2.75)) {  
        return c*(7.5625*t*t) + b;  
    } else if (t < (2/2.75)) {  
        return c*(7.5625*(t-(1.5/2.75))*t + .75) + b;  
    } else if (t < (2.5/2.75)) {  
        return c*(7.5625*(t-(2.25/2.75))*t + .9375) + b;  
    } else {  
        return c*(7.5625*(t-(2.625/2.75))*t + .984375) + b;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Don't know if it's related, but aren't you missing a '*' in the last 2 return statements?

Comment: Does the `@interface` declaration of this class contain the `easeOutBounce:andB:andC:andD:` method?

Comment: Please post full compiler output for the file in question. My best guess is that you’re missing some other warnings, like for example, the compiler hasn’t seen the method declaration so it has assumed it returns id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the compiler encounters an unknown method (i.e. a method that is being used but hasn't been declared in an `@interface`, or previously defined in an `@implementation`), the compiler will issue a warning, and assume that the method returns `id`, which is a pointer type, which you can't assign to a `float` type.

Make sure that your `@interface` has the declaration for your `easeOutBounce:andB:andC:andD:` method, or, at the very least, make sure that this method is defined *above* the code that uses it.

For example:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    float myVar;
}
-(float) easeOutBounce:(float)t andB:(float)b andC:(float)c andD:(float)d;
@end
```